# DotNetNuke portal alias localhost problem

Tags: dotnetnuke-8

I deployed a website using DNN 8.0, everything works fine except that it cannot be accessed from outside, as it always redirect to “http://127.0.0.1/dnn”, and i’ve added alias “192.168.20.38/dnn”, it still redirect to localhost, and also try different alias mode, and changed the primary flag in between, but still failed. Any clues?

Answer (score 0):

192.168.20.38 is a local IP address that is not routed. You need either a public IP address or a host name for that.